# About Scaling an Edge towards Outside

Tags: scale

I have a mesh and added an edge around it to scale out to give it a little curve on sides(picture1). Normally when you scale the edge around, it scales towards outside equally. But with my mesh, it acts different(picture2). I just wonder if it is normal or something causing it.

Picture1:
[image]

Picture2:
[image]

Comment: You should consider Scaling along the geometric surface Normal ... or more casually the Normal.  See Shrink Fatten on the Menus.  Check the Pivot Center setting on the Edit Mode Menu Area. A suggestion is to resubmit your images so that the Edit Mode Menu Area is visible for readers to see the settings.

Comment: The first answer submitted is showing Shrink Fatten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in Object mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply rotation and scale.  Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> instead of just pressing <kbd>S</kbd> to scale.  This should scale the edge out proportionally.

This demonstrates the difference between <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I always thought S key scaled equally on all directions. I have learned something new with your visual comparison. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Mehmet - You're very welcome.  The S key will multiply all selected edges by the scalar value that you input... but the directional part of the edge's vector will remain the same.